# I want to make 10/2 an int not a float

Tags: python, division

10/2 is 5 but pyhton says its 5.0 I want it to be 5 while making 11/2 5.5 which still makes it a float
so basically thing that wouldnt be a float should be int but things like 4.3 should stay a float

`

```
user_input = 10

prime_verification = user_input / 2

if isinstance(prime_verification, int):
    print(user_input)
```

the output is false because 5.0 is a float and I want it to be int so it becomes true`

Comment: that makes the decimal gone but I want the decimal for actual floats but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: `nb = int(nb) if int(nb) == nb else nb`

Comment: Decimal for the actual floats. Could you please elaborate whats the expected output

Comment: So in your code : `prime_verification = int(user_input/2) if int(user_input/2) == user_input/2 else user_input / 2`

Comment: lets say the user inputs a number and its 12, I divide it by 2 and I get 6.0, that counts as float if I do int that gets me 6 which is an integer but the problem is when someone does 13 now the answer is 6.5 but because its int it is still 6

Comment: Why are you using the type of the result for anything? What if `user_input` is *not* even?

Comment: well I was trying to know if a number is a prime number and I thought if a number ist divided by 2, 3, 5, 7 its a prime thats why  I want to know if the results is a float or an int

Comment: if its int than its not a prime number

Comment: You want to look at the *remainder* when dividing, not the quotient.

Answer (score 0):

The previous comment is correct using `//` will give an `int`

```py
number = 10 // 2
print(number)
print(isinstance(number, int))
```

Output:

```py
5
True
```

Comment: but if the number changes to 11 the output is 5 when it should have been 5.5

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `/` or `//`. If you want to know if `n` is divisible by 2, 3, etc, use `%` to check the *remainder*:

```
user_input = 10

prime_verification = user_input % 2

if prime_verification == 0:  # user_input was divisible by 2
    print(user_input)
```

(Of course, to be prime, it has to be true that `user_input % k != 0` for all the `k` less than `user_input`, not just one value. This answer only addresses the divisibility test that's part of primality testing.)

Answer (score -1):

Use the `//` Operator. This coverts your variable into an int
user_input = 10

```
prime_verification = user_input // 2

if isinstance(prime_verification, int):
    print(user_input)
```

Comment: `//` doesn't convert anything.

Answer (score -1):

The `//` operator performs division and converts to integer. Try this:

```py
user_input = 11
divisor = 2

prime_verification = user_input // divisor

if isinstance(prime_verification, int) and user_input%divisor == 0:
    print(user_input)
    print(prime_verification)
else:
    prime_verification = user_input / divisor
    print(user_input)
    print(prime_verification)
    print("Input could not be converted to integer. ")
```

Edited to reflect the output to be 5.5 when the input couldn't be converted to integer. The code above properly tells you when the division result could not be properly cast to integer.

Comment: There's no conversion. `user_input // 2` is an integer for *all* integers, whether or not ethey are divisible by 2.

Comment: Added a check for the modulus now. Must have misunderstood the original aim. The edited code above should fix this

Comment: The `isinstance` check is useless; if `user_input` and `divisor` are `int`s to start with, then `user_input // divisor` will *always* be an `int`. (And if either one is not, then the result will *never* be an `int`.)